PCIe 1.0 card does not work on PCIe 2.0 8X motherboard
I have a tv tunner card that is pcie1.0a and a motherboard with just one pcie slot that it PCIe 2.0 8x speed. In bios I can set the speed of the slot to either 4x4x or 8x.
When I insert the card to my motherboard the card is not being detected. According to ASRock the card can not work with my motherboard (c2550d4i) because the motherboard can not set the the width of the pcie slot to gen 1.
I tried some other card (usb-c) on the pcie slot and it works fine so I do not think that the motherboard is faulty. I am also running the tv tuner card on another machine and also runs fine so the card is not faulty either.
I was under the impression that PCIe slots are both forward and backward compatible so I was expecting this card to work with my motherboard when I first try it. I understand that sometimes pcie cards do not work as expected on some motherboards and in these cases you need to modify the bios to make it work 100% reliable but still I never heard of a card not being detected at all.
Does someone ever experience such a behavior in the past and perhaps knows of a workaround? If the pcie width is the problem is there a way to reduce the link width of the motherboard pcie slot by using an adapter or something else?

The physical PCIe standard is backwards compatible but if the firmware doesn’t support then you are out of luck. Any adapter would require setting the speed to something that the firmware doesn’t support

By firmware you mean the bios or a firmware on the card it self?

BIOS and UEFI are both considered to be firmware.

I see so if the bios does not support for the pcie to be backward compatible then it is not. thanks for the info.

I assume that ASROCK has a reason to indicate that the PCIe card is incompatible with the motherboard. I have an educated guess that it has to do with the slot's inability to set the PCIe mode. You likely would have different results with a different motherboard.

PCIe is supposed to be both forwards AND backwards compatible.  However, ASROCK is preventing it from happening for some reason.  If they say it cant be done, then it cant.

Too bad. I tried the card in two motherboards (DH67CL and an Asus - do not remember the model right now) and it works just fine.  They must have indeed block it for some reason but they should have listed as much in the website on the model so people know.
